# Laravel slow to not loading after transferring the project file from one pc to the other

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I just want to ask what's happening here.

My laravel project had painfully slow loading times and sometimes not loading at all after I transfer my project from my work pc to my personal pc.

I tried everything I know that can solve this problem but to no avail.
What I tried:

- clearing cache
- composer update and install

I also tried to create a new project and the loading times are fine.
Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: All sorts of things, encryption keys, cache, public folder needs to be rebuilt, route cache, storage, seeding, tools, composer updates, etc..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.